# enter all objects inside mongoid criteria

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, mongoid

I have inside `params[:admin_ids]` the next ids:

```
["50a62c8e1d41c8103f000001", "50a62af21d41c81502000006"]
```

I can storage in array these objects with these ids:

```
 admins = []
 for id in params[:admin_ids]
  admins << Admin.find("#{id}")
 end
```

No my question is:

**How I can I load these two objects instead of an array, load these two objects in a** `Mongoid::Criteria`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this questions is use:

```
admins = Admin.criteria.for_ids(params[:admin_ids])
```